# How to invoke a formhandler using ATG REST Client

Tags: rest, atg, oracle-commerce

I'm trying to invoke ProfileFormHandler's create handle using ATG rest client as shown below.

```
mSession = RestSession.createSession(mHost, mPort,"kim@example.com","password");
mSession.setUseHttpsForLogin(false);
mSession.login();

Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put("value.login", "buddha@oracle.com");
params.put("value.email", "buddha@oracle.com");
params.put("value.password", "password");

RestResult result = RestComponentHelper.executeMethod("/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler","create",null,params,mSession);
```

I'm getting form exceptions that says, I'm not passing Login and Password Fields.

```
["Missing value for the required property Password",
 "Missing value for the required property Login name"]
```

I've tried all combinations of login and password fields like `value.login`, `Login`, `login`, `value.Login` etc., but nothing seemed to work. All combinations giving the same form exceptions.

How do I invoke an ATG form handler using ATG REST Client and pass parameters to it?

Comment: I meant along with RegistrationFormHandler that I mentioned in the problem.

Comment: What version of ATG are you using?

Comment: Please also provide an extract of your userProfile.xml and any customizations you have done to the ootb RegistrationFormHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely need more information but looking at your code I can see that you have a `value.login` which is not configured ootb and believe this is causing the NPE.  Assuming you have not customized the ootb ATG RegistrationFormHandler and the required field in the repository the only values you need to pass to the form handler are:

- value.email
- value.password
- value.confirmPassword
- value.firstName
- value.lastName

Also, the help is specific that the data-type of the `value` property needs to be `java.util.Dictionary`

Comment: I have used CRS formhandler and I'm using 11.1 version of ATG. In further experimentation, I have used ProfileFormHandler and its handleCreate to avoid any customizations. Now I'm not getting any null pointer exception, but I'm getting form exceptions that say I'm not passing Password and Login fields. Even though I'm passing them.

Comment: Have you followed [these](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s1601invokingformhandlers01.html) instructions?

Comment: These instructions involve directly passing JSON request. can we pass a JSON text using ATG REST Client? I couldn't find any instructions related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to /atg/rest/security/restSecurityConfiguration.xml

```
<resource component="/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler" secure="false">
        <method name="handleCreate" secure="false">
          <acl value="EVERYONE:read,write,execute" />
        </method>
        <property name="value.login" secure="false" />
        <property name="value.password" secure="false" />
    </resource>
```